# What is this data structure that appears as a list, but has key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures

I have seen this a few times in a few node examples but am never quite sure what to make of it. One example is with a `net.Socket`. Here is a socket after a warning has been emitted from data listeners.

```
> commands._events.data
[ [Function], warned: true ];
```

Another example is in using `/^(some)(regex)$/.exec("someregex")`

```
[ 'someregex',
  'some',
  'regex',
  index: 0,
  input: 'someregex' ]
```

I'm not sure I understand what this data structure is. Is it a list or a dictionary? Why does it have indexes, and also key value pairs? I can do `match.index`, but also `match[1]`. How is it constructed?

(sorry if this is a dupe, couldn't find it in google).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an array, but with additional properties.  The example with the regular expression can be explained from [the specification for `exec`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) - see steps 13 and 15 for instance where it creates an array, then adds the `index` property:

> 13. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array() where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name.
> 14. Let matchIndex be i.
> 15. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of A with arguments "index", Property Descriptor {[[Value]]: matchIndex, [[Writable]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true}, and true.

(A is the eventual return value)

You can do the same:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
x['abc'] = 5;
console.log(x);        //[1, 2, 3, abc: 5]
console.log(x.length); //3
console.log(x[1]);     //2
console.log(x.abc);    //5
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense, I didn't even know you could do that. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Worth noting that the output of `console.log(x);` depends on the browser. For example, in Safari on Mac OS X, it outputs `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @EdCottrell Ok.  (In Chrome) if you just put `x` on the console, it also prints just `[1, 2, 3]` - you need the `console.log` to get the additional properties.

Comment: How is x.length 3, shouldn't that be 4?

Comment: @harsimranb No - there are 3 elements in the array.  The array has an additional property, but it's not counted as an element in the array.  Note that the `length` property isn't counted either.

Comment: Ah thanks!  That makes sense now.  Good interview question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript everything that is not a primitive is an object.

Arrays are also objects in JavaScript. They have special functions and properties that make them behave as a collection but all the rules of objects still apply to them.